# How do I find a random instance (and index) of a certain value in a list in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, random

I am stuck on a simple way of finding all the instances of a value in a list and randomly selecting one.

I only want to select from the occurrences of `Value`

I found some stuff on `List.index(Value)`
But it only returns the index of the first instance of that value in my list.

Is there some simple way of returning a list of all the occurrences of the value.
Example:

```
Instances = List.allindexes(Value)  # for example
SelectedIndex = random.choice(Instances) # select a random instance of Value
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed the Index rather than the literal value:

```
Scores = # some list of numbers
Indexes = []
for a in Scores: # iterate through all the scores 
    if a == Value:
        Indexes.append(a) # if the score == Value then add it to the list of viable indexes
FinalIndex = random.choice(Indexes) # Finally choose a random instance of the Value
```

Answer (score 4):

Pick a random integer between 0 and the length of the list instead:

```
Instances = List.allindexes(Value)  # for example
random_index = random.randrange(len(Instances))
random_element = Instances[random_index]
```

Now you have both an index and the object it refers to.

It is not clear from your question if *all* elements of your list are eligible for random selection. If not, use `enumerate()` and filter down the list first, then use `random.choice()` on the filtered list:

```
random_index, random_element = random.choice(
    [(i, elem) for (i, elem) in enumerate(Instances) 
     if elem == 'some match'])
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to get the index of a random occurence of the value you are looking for in Python 3 is this:

```
import random
random.choice(list(filter(lambda x: List[x] == Value, range(len(List)))))
```

This takes the indices in your list (range(len(List))), filters them so only the indices of Value remain and chooses one at random.